# Jetpack compose Instrumented test performTextInput sometimes replaces whole text

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

Usually Instrumented tests `performTextInput(..)` method adds text to existing text, but in some rare cases it replaces whole text.

I was not able to create a small reproduceable code where it will happen often.
But basically I have tests where I check that cursor inside field is still in the correct position and it will write new text to where cursor is located:

```kotlin
val textBeforeCursor = "abc"
val textAfterCursor = "def"
composeRule.onNodeWithTag("item_field1").assertTextEquals("${textBeforeCursor}${textAfterCursor}")

// And now when I performTextInput to add a text to cursor position
val middleText = "ghi"
composeRule.onNodeWithTag("item_field1").performTextInput(middleText)
composeRule.onNodeWithTag("item_field1").assertTextEquals("${textBeforeCursor}${middleText}${textAfterCursor}")
// This assert in some rare cases fails and it says that actual text = ${middleText}
// Which means it has replace previous text with new one
```

I looked a bit into compose code and in `EditCommand.kt` there is a following code. And text replacement seems to be happen when buffer.hasComposition() condition is true.

```kotlin
override fun applyTo(buffer: EditingBuffer) {
    // API description says replace ongoing composition text if there. Then, if there is no
    // composition text, insert text into cursor position or replace selection.
    if (buffer.hasComposition()) {
        buffer.replace(buffer.compositionStart, buffer.compositionEnd, text)
    } else {
        // In this editing buffer, insert into cursor or replace selection are equivalent.
        buffer.replace(buffer.selectionStart, buffer.selectionEnd, text)
    }
    ...
}
```

I've not been able to reproduce this with manual testing, but I'm still wondering can this text replacement issue happen when user is actually using the app.

But my workaround to fix a test case:

```kotlin
try {
    composeRule.onNodeWithTag("item_field1").assertTextEquals("${textBeforeCursor}${middleText}${textAfterCursor}")
} catch (e: AssertionError) {
    composeRule.onNodeWithTag("item_field1").assertTextEquals(middleText)
}
```

But to be honest I really don't like this workaround, it's seems quite hacky. Is there some better ways how to solve this?